# returning a boolean if a DB field contains data

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an object model that contains a boolean MyBool and I have a table that contains a field MyField. I'm writing a linq-to-sql query that should returning a list of objects with MyBool set to true or false depending on if MyField has a value.

This is what I have so far:

```
var TheListOfObjects = (from thetable in MyDC.TheTable
                        ....
                        select new MyObject()
                        {
                            MyBool = thetable.MyField.Contains("*")

                         }).ToList();
```

I the error: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type. Doesn't Contains return a bool?

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know a lick about linq, but the SQL syntax is the EXISTS keyword... IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table) BEGIN. Adding that to your Google efforts might get you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want a nullable property in MyObject you can check for null when you are assigning

```
var TheListOfObjects = (from thetable in MyDC.TheTable
                        ....
                        select new MyObject()
                        {
                            MyBool = (thetable.MyField == null) ? false : thetable.MyField.Contains("*") //check if it's null in-line

                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, would this also work: MyBool = (thetable.MyField == null) ? false : true

Comment: that will work, but you can condense it even further 'MyBool = (thetable.MyField == null)'

Answer (score 2):

Haris Hasan is correct. In order to really understand this issue think about what SQL your C# code might turn into:

```
(CHARINDEX(MyField, '*', 1) - 1)
```

But if MyField is null, this expression turns into null itself!

Linq2Sql does not guarantee C# semantics! It provides a good approximation of C# semantics, but yet it is close to the SQL model.

You can fix this by either saying

```
MyBool = (bool?)thetable.MyField.Contains("*") ?? false
```

or by saying

```
MyBool = thetable.MyField != null && thetable.MyField.Contains("*")
```

You could also make MyBool nullable but that is probably not what you indend.

Btw, you will get the same strange behavior when you do a left-join that "fails", because SQL will fill the joined row with NULL's.

Comment: ok, I got it; would this also work:  MyBool = (thetable.MyField == null) ? false : true

Comment: It would, although it is a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your bool variable nullable so that it can accept possible null value returned by DB

Change  `bool MyBool {get;set;}` to `bool? MyBool {get;set;}`

Comment: I know this would fix it but I'm looking to keep the object model as is and instead change the query.